# How to create multiple contenttypes in 1 xml file in Visual Studio?

Tags: content-type

I would like to create 3 contenttypes and would like to avoid 3 xml files. Is it possible to create 3 contenttypes in 1 xml file? Do I need to create a element or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ContentType ID="0x010012364FC276D949B4BC833B1838C7BC09"
                   Name=""
                   Group=""
                   Inherits="TRUE"
                   Version="0">
        <FieldRefs>
          // Add Your fields here..
        </FieldRefs>    
    </ContentType>   
    <ContentType ID="[Base Contentype ID][00][32 Character GUID]"
                   Name=""
                   Group=""
                   Inherits="TRUE"
                   Version="0">
        <FieldRefs>
          // Add Your fields here..
        </FieldRefs>   
</ContentType>
```

Here, 
**0x01** =  Base content type id
**00**  = Use for separation (necessary to create new content type GUID)
**12364FC276D949B4BC833B1838C7BC09** = Custom content type 32 character GUID.

you can create GUID from **visual studio > TOOLS> NEW GUID**

You can create number of content types in single Element.XML file.